# Which is the best way to update database in python django from the list

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3

I have the database tables where my folders or categories are stored in table

`class Node` and Files are stored in class `File`

In `Node` and `File` model i have field called `key` which is the string key from amazon s3 files

like

`mybucket/files/pdf/abc.pdf`

I update the databse by running custom build python function.

Now what i want is that i want to see which files on amazon S3 has been changed or deleted or which new files are added.

In short i will have the list of all amazon keys  like this  `s3_keys`

```
mybucket/files/pdf/abc.pdf
mybucket/files/pdf/abc2.pdf
mybucket/files/pdf/abc3.pdf
mybucket/files/pdf/abc4.pdf
mybucket/files/pdf/new/
mybucket/files/pdf/new/abc.pdf
mybucket/files/pdf/2011/
```

then i will have keys in two database tables i.e `Node` and `File` in colum key

I want that somwhow i can compare the `s3_keys` with keys field in database and then if

1. keys are same then it wont do anything
2. keys are on s3 and not in database then i put in `new_list`
3. if keys are in databse and not in s3 then i have `delete_list`

then i can do operation on them

Whats the best way to approach this

UPDTAE:

I am thiking of having three lists

```
Nodes_List = [(pk, key), .....]
File_List = [(pk, key), .....]
s3_keys = [key1, key2, .....]
```

The i have to filterout the elements

Comment: what are the sizes of the tables?

Comment: @eran  Node will have max 100 , File will have max 5000 rows

Comment: so if tables are so small just bring all the data to python and do the manipulation in python itself.

Comment: @eran that is what i am asking , best way for that so that i make less databse queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said that your tables are small, you can do the following. 
I assume you can do better by using raw queries, but you can consider the following approach (Hope that code contains no errors).

s3_keys = [list of s3 keys]

Now you want to delete all entries that are not in s3 keys, I think this is simple:

```
File.objects.exclude(id___in=s3_keys).delete()
Node.objects.exclude(id___in=s3_keys).delete()
```

Now you want to add s3 which are not in the list to the DB:

```
#Bring all entries and make them to a set:
db_keys = set(File.objects.all().values_list('key',flat=True))
# find the new keys
new_db_keys = set(s3_keys) - db_keys
```

Now do [bulk create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create):

```
new_nodes = []
new_files = []
for key in new db_keys:
   new_nodes.append(Node(key=key))
   new_files.append(File(key=key))
Node.objects.bulk_create(new_nodes)
File.objects.bulk_create(new_files)
```